# Matlab VectorA/VectorB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, translation

I'm currently translating my matlabcode to python and i have a line in Matlab like

```
X = VectorA/VectorB;
```

with x being a single scalar value and VectorA and VectorB are each arrays with the size 1x1750.
But i can't manage to translate this into python code, I know it's a linear equation system that should work via numpy.linalg.solve(a, b) in python, but it wants b to be a square matrix and doesnt work. Whether I'm not using the correct function and/or mess up the syntax, in dont know.

Can you guys help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `np.linalg.lstsq` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq).

```py
a = np.ndarray((2,1), buffer=np.array([1, 2, 3]), dtype=int)
b = np.ndarray((2,1), buffer=np.array([2, 4, 6]), dtype=int)

# Solve for X = b/a, or a * X = b
X, resid, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)  # X = array([[2.]])
```

Comment: okay, values for x are supposed to be values like "0.0584" or "0.94152" but np.linalg.lstsq seemingly keeps cutting off the numbers after . leaving me with "0". how do i get my float values?
When i use rcond=float or rcond='float' i always get:
ValueError: _flapack.dgelsd_lwork() 1st keyword (cond) can't be converted to double

Comment: i was looking arround a bit and 
 
x = mldivide(VectorB'\VectorA')'  in matlab gives the same as X = VectorA/VectorB

Comment: okay, your solution works, my dumb ass used the wrong vector (which was lin, independent), what caused the 0 as result, thank you for your help, have a nice day